# How to avoid multiple gems under shared bundle folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

How to avoid multiple gems under shared bundle folder, when doing a deploy using the capistrano command. Most of the times when I migrate a gem from a version to another the shared bundle folder still contains both the versions, causing issues. How should we avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I ever saw conflicts like this. But I have extended capistrano `deploy:cleanup` task with cleaning outdated bundler gems:

```
after "deploy:cleanup", "bundle:clean"

namespace :bundle do
  task :clean, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    bundle_cmd = fetch(:bundle_cmd, "bundle")
    run "cd #{latest_release} && #{bundle_cmd} clean"
  end
end
```

If it causes you conflicts, you can probably do it after `deploy` instead.

Comment: Will this break `deploy:rollback`? If the older version of code relies on a different version of a gem, rollback will fail because the gem has been cleaned up.  May need to hook rollback to also `bundle install` again?

Answer (score 1):

khustochka's answer above solved my problem perfectly. However, if your system is using Capistrano v3, the syntax has changed significantly. I used the following:

```
namespace :bundle do
  task :clean do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, :clean
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

after "deploy:cleanup", "bundle:clean"
```

~