# Capistrano deployment to rails application (specifcally, bundle install) not working after updating software on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, rubygems, passenger

Disclaimer: I didn't write the Capistrano recipe or set up the (FreeBSD) server, I inherited everything from a developer who now works elsewhere. Learning as I go.

Changes I made to the server since last week Friday, not sure which is causing deployments to fail:

1) Updated Ruby using ports.
2) Recompiled Passenger/Apache.
3) Updated rubygems. (`gem update --system`)

If I issue `bundle install --without development test` locally on the server, bundle is successful. Capistrano attempts to execute: `cd /usr/local/docs/arc/releases/20140411143706 && bundle install --gemfile /usr/local/docs/arc/releases/20140411143706/Gemfile --path /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test` and results in:

`Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/Ascii85-1.0.2.gemspec.rz.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for
verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and
change 'https' to 'http'.`

This led me to believe I should change the gem sources to only fetch gems using `http://rubygems.org`. Verified gem sources by issuing `gem sources`, there was only the `https://rubygems.org` entry. I replaced it with the `http` entry and attempted deploying with Capistrano once more. Same results as noted above.

What should I do to fix this? I feel like I need to re-bundle something. It's as though old changes are sticking around.

Comment: Just a guess: Have you installed security/ca_root_nss? With a symlink into /etc/ssl/?

Comment: I'm not sure. I did navigate to /usr/ports/security/ca_root_nss but don't see a symlink to /etc/ssl. Would that even be the correct location?

Comment: I mean the symlink is created by an option of the port (check ETCSYMLINK when `make config`). I don't know if the binary package create it, I don't use them (if not you may need to do it manually: `ln -snf /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt /etc/ssl/cert.pem`?).

Comment: The developer whose place I took left notes about OpenSSL configuration being tricky. I'm hesitant to modify any configuration for fear things may just stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Check the first few lines of your Gemfile, usually you will find something like

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

change this to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Note: Maybe emptying /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle before will be necessary. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314291/how-to-avoid-multiple-gems-under-shared-bundle-folder) how to clean up your shared bundler directory.

Comment: `/usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle` is a directory which has `ruby` as a child directory. `ruby` further has `1.9` and `1.9.1` child directories, Each has `bin`, `bundler`, `cache`, `doc`, `gems` and `specifications` directories. Any advice?

Comment: you can safely nuke the content of the whole directory. It will get recreated by the bundler

Comment: I'm apprehensive about doing this in a production environment. >.<

Comment: You can go ahead and try that on a dev machine: export an environment variable <pre>RAILS_ENV=production</pre> and your dev machine will act as if it is a production machine.